# object java class code

Tags: java, class, object

These are the instructions for this assignment. Any help would be appreciated. I am  a rookie when it comes to java and cant seem to figure this out.

This exercise has two classes. The first class is named `ObjectsToArrayList`. The second class is called just `Objects`.

> Your responsibility is to create the Object class and figure out how the ObjectsToArrayList class works.
>
> The `ObjectsToArraylist` class will create an `ArrayList` of objects. It will ask for and populate the data fields of an `Object`, then add it to the `ArrayList`. This can be done for as many instances of the `Object` that the user wants to enter.
>
> Requirements for the Object Class.
>
> - 2 data fields: int obj_id, String obj_name.
> - 2 Constructors: No-Arg and one that takes both values and assigns them to the data field.
> - Gets and sets for both data fields
> - A `toString()` method that returns output like:
>
>   ```
>     The object ID is 22 and the name is Andrea
>   ```

Here's my code

```
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Student
 */
public class ObjectsToArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList <Object> objectList = new ArrayList();
        
        
        System.out.println("Please enter information for your favorite object!");
        do {  // collect an indicator to determine the method to call
            Object object = new Object();
            System.out.println("Enter a whole number for the ID of your object:\n"
                    + "or enter 99 to quit.");
             int tmpInt = input.nextInt();
            // if 99 is entered exit the loop.
            if (tmpInt == 99) {
                break;
            }
            object.setObj_id(tmpInt);
            input.nextLine();
            // ask for the Object Name
            System.out.println("Please enter the name of the Object:");
            object.setObj_name(input.nextLine());
            
            objectList.add(object);
          

        } while (true);  // this is a contineous loop if the break isn't included.
        
        for(Object object:objectList) {
            System.out.println(object.toString());
        }
    }   
}

//****************************************************
//**** Objects Class is below this block            **
//****************************************************

class Object {

      // enter object code here (This is the part I cannot figure out)
}
```

Comment: What can't you figure out? Also, the name of the class should be `Objects`, not `Object`.

Comment: The first class was given, right? So although it looks like you did most of the job already, you basically ask us to do your homework...

Comment: "the part I cannot figure out" is how to write all of the class? Then go read a tutorial on classes and objects in java. SO is for specific, narrow problems, not for cases where you have no idea what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here are examples of constructors:

```
class Objects{
    // This is a constructor with no argument
    public Objects(){
    }

    // This is a constructor with 2 arguments
    public Objects(int obj_id, String obj_name){
    }

}
```

You can refer in the link below to learn more about creating constructors and assigning values to fields:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Note: Do not use Object as a class because Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public class ObjectsToArrayList {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList <Object> objectList = new ArrayList();


    System.out.println("Please enter information for your favorite object!");
    do {  // collect an indicator to determine the method to call
        Object object = new Object();
        System.out.println("Enter a whole number for the ID of your object:\n"
                + "or enter 99 to quit.");
         int tmpInt = input.nextInt();
        // if 99 is entered exit the loop.
        if (tmpInt == 99) {
            break;
        }
        object.setObj_id(tmpInt);//runs the setObj_id method in the Objects class 
                                 //for the users input
        input.nextLine();
        // ask for the Object Name
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the Object:");
        object.setObj_name(input.nextLine());//runs the setObj_name method in the Objects class 
                                             //for the users input

        objectList.add(object);


    } while (true);  // this is a contineous loop if the break isn't included.
    for(Object object:objectList) {
        System.out.println(object.toString());//prints out what the toString method returns in
                                              //the Objects class
    }
}   
}

//****************************************************
//**** Objects Class is below this block            **
//****************************************************

public class Objects
{
    //add stuff like methods and instance variables
    private int ID;
    private String name;

    public Objects(){//default constructor
    } 

    public Objects(int i, String n){//constructor to change both ID and name at the same time
        ID = i;
        name = n;
    }

    public void setObj_id(int i){//constructor to change only ID
        ID = i;
    }

    public void setObj_name(String n){//constructor to change only name
        name = n;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return (name + ": " + ID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you want to create your own object soo have 2 classes rather, personProfile and arrayOfProfiles

So class personDetails object note seperate class file not *not in same file

```
class personProfile{
private int ID = 0;
private String Name = "";

  public personProfile(int id,String name){
    ID = id;
     Name = name; 
  }

 public int getID(){
   return ID;
 }
 public String getName(){
   return name;
 }

}
```

now the other class* different file

```
class arrayOfProfiles{
  personProfile profiles[] = new personProfile[0];

  public personProfile[] array(){
    return profiles;
  }
  public void addProfileToArray(personProfile profileObject){
    personProfile arrayMod = new personProfile[profiles.length+1];

    for(int i = 0;i<profiles.length;i++){
      arrayMod[i] = profiles[i];
    }
    arrayMod[arrayMod.length-1] = profileObject;
  }

public static void main(String args[]){
  arrayOfProfiles profiles = new arrayOfProfiles();

  for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){
    int id = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter ID ");
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter name");

    profiles.addProfileToArray(new personProfile(id,name));
  }
  for(int i =0;i<profiles.array().length;i++){
    System.out.println("ID :"+profiles[i].getID()+" name - "+profiles[i].getName());
  }
}


}
```